# CUPS server-error-internal-error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, printing, printer, cups

I am trying to install a printer in Ubuntu 22.04.

Via the "Settings" app, it tries to download drivers then fails with "Failed to add new printer".

Via `system-config-printer-gnome` I get

```
Caught non-fatal exception.  Traceback:
File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/newprinter.py", line 4235, in getNPPPD
    ppd = cups.PPD(f)
RuntimeError: ppdOpenFile failed
Continuing anyway..
```

in the command line and `There was an error during the CUPS operation: server-error-internal-error'` in the GUI

I am a member of the `lpadmin` group.

How can I get more details on why this is failing?

Comment: CUPS almost certainly has logs. Check them. Also, the error from somewhat helpful: A PPD (PostScript Printer Definition) file could not be opened for whatever reason. Maybe it’s malformed. Maybe its filesystem permissions are incorrect.